# Excel VBA Run-time error 5 when creating text files

Tags: vba, excel

I'm exporting a large number of data (100k rows) from excel into separate text files. Each text file should contain 200 rows worth of data (just copying values from one column). It works fine for the first 14 files and then chokes halfway through file 15. I get: "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument". There is nothing special about the data in the row that it fails on.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Create_Text_Files()
Dim row As Long, lastRow As Long, increment As Long, j As Long
Dim fso As Object
Dim strPath
Dim oFile As Object
increment = 199
j = 1

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
For row = 2 To lastRow
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strPath = "C:\data\" & Cells(row, "A").Value & j & ".txt"
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strPath)

    For i = row To row + increment
        oFile.WriteLine Cells(i, "F").Value
    Next
    oFile.Close

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
    row = i + 1
    j = j + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Any insight would be much appreciated!

EDIT: The data looked mundane enough, but after deleting the row it was erroring out on the script continued on for a little while longer before erroring out again. It seems that the script is failing on non-standard characters.

I guess that makes this a different kind of question now. Is there an encoding flag or something like that that I can set to smooth the transition of the spreadsheet data to a .txt format? I'd like to avoid going through all 100k records and removing non-standard characters one by one...

EDIT 2: Turns out there were only about a dozen lines of data that needed to be changed, so I was able to do it by hand. I am thinking that was the cause of the error all along, but thanks to Tim for offering a streamlined version of the code.

Comment: erl value is listed as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to modify your loop counter within the loop - it can lead to hard-to-track errors.

```
Sub Create_Text_Files()

Const ROWS_PER_FILE As Long = 200
Dim row As Long, lastRow As Long, j As Long, i As Long
Dim fso As Object, oFile As Object
Dim strPath

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

i = 0
j = 1
For row = 2 To lastRow

    If i Mod ROWS_PER_FILE = 0 Then
        If Not oFile Is Nothing Then oFile.Close
        strPath = "C:\data\" & Cells(row, "A").Value & j & ".txt"
        Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strPath)
        j = j + 1
    End If

    oFile.WriteLine Cells(row, "F").Value
    i = i + 1
Next

If Not oFile Is Nothing Then oFile.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: You know, I thought that this would work, but it is actually giving me the same error. Fails at the same point - 2,919 rows in. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @TwoHundredOK I presumed you got this working given you accepted it?

Comment: Yes, please see Edit 1 and 2 in original post.

Comment: Note that {dim I as Long} was added. You should use {Option Explicit} at the top of the module.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect A2919 contains a prohibited filename character such as / \ ? % * : | " < >

Comment: Close but not quite. The filename wasn't the issue. Incorrectly translated UTF-8 characters in the cells that were being copied into the file were to blame.